# Possible to prove this via adjunction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X\overset{f'}\to S$ and $T\overset{g}\to S$ be schemes over $S=Spec(k)$ for a field $k$. Further, let $X_T = X \underset{S}\times T$ denote the fiber product over $S$, and $f$ the induced map $X_T\to T$. I run into the claim
$$ \Gamma(X_T,\; \mathcal{O}_{X_T}) \cong \Gamma(T,\; f_*\mathcal{O}_{X_T}), $$
and I shoved to myself that this is the case by the identitfications of functors
$$ \Gamma(X_T, \square) \cong (g\circ f)_* \square \cong g_* \;f_* \square \cong \Gamma(T, f_*\square). $$

I have two questions:

1. Is there some kind of adjunction formula or well-known result that
   implies the above claim?
2. Do I really need the hypothesis $S=Spec(k)$, or does this work over an arbitrary scheme $S$?

Comment: I don't understand your formulas. How can you do $g \circ f$ when $f : X \to S$ and $g : T \to S$?

Comment: Also what do you mean by $\Gamma(T,f_\ast \mathcal{O}_{X_T})$? Your $f$ is a map from $X$ to $S$.

Comment: I agree with @Benja that your notation doesn't make sense. If $T$ were affine, say $\text{spec }A$ it's possible (although unlikely from your notation) that you are perhaps trying to prove that $\mathcal{O}_{X_T}(X_T)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)\otimes_k A$. In this case the requirement that $k$ is a field is important since we can leave off an annoying flatness hypothesis.

Comment: I was using the same f for $f:X\to S$ and for the pullback map $X_T\to T$. Now I changed the first one to $f'$, sorry for being sloppy about that, but from the source I'm reading it looked like it's a common way to denote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, this is clear by definition of $f_\ast$:

The sheaf $f_\ast \mathcal O_{X_T}$ is given by associating to an open subset $U$ of $T$ the set $\mathcal O_{X_T}(f^{-1}(U))$. So a global section of $f_\ast \mathcal O_{X_T}$ is just given by $$\Gamma(T,f_\ast \mathcal O_{X_T})=\mathcal O_{X_T}(f^{-1}(T))=\mathcal O_{X_T}(X_T)=\Gamma(X_T,\mathcal O_{X_T})$$

For the second question, this clearly works over any base scheme. You don't even have to talk about fiber products.